# RSS Feed in Flutter blocked by Cloudflare - Execute javascript in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, cloudflare, rss-reader

I'm making a RSS reader in flutter, however my requests to the feed are blocked by Cloudflare.
I've been looking for a way to emulate a browser with javascript enabled, since it is needed to pass the Cloudflare test, but nothing seems to have that functionality.
What I need is a simulated browser, that renders the page requested, execute the javascript contained in the page. I haven't found anything that claims to do that aside from webview_flutter, which is a widget and thus cannot be used I my case.
I find it weird that there is no such thing as a simulated browser for Flutter, so I must have missed something.